# Populating data in appengine database from a csv file or spreadsheet from google docs

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am uisng webapp2 on google app engine my database model has the following schema:

```
class Match(db.Model):
    start_date = db.DateProperty()
    start_time = db.TimeProperty()
    team1 = db.StringProperty()
    team2 = db.StringProperty()
    venue = db.StringProperty()
    result = db.IntegerProperty()
```

And i have a csv file or say google spreadsheet, with all the data there are around 150 rows.

Putting all the values manually is a big pain. Could anyone please suggest me how to update the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a page that you can POST the contents of the CSV file to, and then use the Python `csv` module to read the file and loop over the rows, inserting model instances as you go.

Comment: i faintly get what you mean. could you please elaborate a little, i am little new as might be evident from my rating.

Comment: I'd suggest reading the AppEngine docs on how to handle requests and read POST data.